# How do I use the and operator in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following query:

```
const records = await Product.findAll({ 
    where: { 
        name: { 
            [Op.like]: '%iphone%' 
        } 
        Op.and( category {[Op.like]: '%phone%'})
    }
})
```

It works well if I just have:

```
const records = await Product.findAll({ 
    where: { 
        name: { 
            [Op.like]: '%iphone%' 
        } 
    } 
})
```

How can I have it such that the query behaves like

`SELECT * FROM Product WHERE name LIKE '%iphone%' AND 'category LIKE '%phone%'`

I keep getting a syntax error, could someone please help me fix this error.
Thanks in advance

Comment: For one, your more elaborate code doesn't look like valid JS, so: are you getting any console errors? I'd entirely expect to see a `TypeError`. Step 1: _format your code_ so that it's not all on a single line, which makes things like missing commas, colons, etc., super obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some commas. [WHERE clause documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#applying-where-clauses)

```
const records = await Product.findAll({ 
    where: { 
        name: { [Op.like]: '%iphone%' },
        category: {[Op.like]: '%phone%'}
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As @MSekrst answered, Every property in `where` object automatically takes each condition concatenated by `AND` statement.

But the answer seems to me incomplete. The answer lacks how to use `AND` operator in Sequelize `WHERE` statement.

The proper way of using `Op.and` would be like following.

```
const records = await Product.findAll({ 
    where: {
        [Op.and] : [
            {
                name: { [Op.like]: '%iphone%' }
            },
            {
                category: {[Op.like]: '%phone%'}
            }
        ]        
    } 
})
```

In these way you can mix up custom setup of `AND` & `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue by explicitly doing the and operation via Op.and.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30022962)